# How to create a Traefik v2.x ReplacePath label in a simple docker-compose file?

Tags: traefik

Given the following url's, I'm trying to create some routers with Traefik v2.x

```
Route             forwards to
-----------------------------
/users         -> /users
/users/*       -> /users/*
/users/swagger -> /swagger
```

So in these examples, my webserver is has some endpoints for users `GET /users, GET /users/1, POST /users, DELETE /users/1, etc..` but also has a Swagger/OpenApi definition/docs located `/swagger`.

So I'm trying to access these endpoints through Traefik.

I'm under the impression that I need to create `labels` that use the routers + PathPrefex and routers + Path for the endpoint matching ... but use [middleware for the replace](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/replacepath/#replacepath).

I'm too sure how to do this properly.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  users-api:
    image: spike.openapi/users.api
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: src/Users/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - backend
    container_name: users.api
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.users-api.rule=PathPrefix(`/users`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.users-api.rule=Path(`/users/swagger`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.users-api.entrypoints=web"

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    <snipped>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the Host rule, traefik will not know on which backend to redirect the request so the first thing you are missing might be that. I think following should work.

```
services:

  users-api:
    ...
    labels:
      # /users/swagger -> /swagger
      traefik.http.middlewares.replacepath-middleware.replacepath.path: /swagger
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.rule: Host(`your-domain.net`) && PathPrefix(`/users/swagger`)
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.middlewares: replacepath-middleware
      # everything else (/users -> /users)
      traefik.http.routers.base-router.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.base-router.rule: Host(`your-domain.net`)
```

You could also use the stripprefix middleware to achieve the exact same thing

```
services:

  users-api:
    ...
    labels:
      # /users/swagger -> /swagger
      traefik.http.middlewares.stripprefix-middleware.stripprefix.prefixes: /users
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.rule: Host(`your-domain.net`) && PathPrefix(`/users/swagger`)
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.middlewares: stripprefix-middleware
      # everything else (/users -> /users)
      traefik.http.routers.base-router.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.base-router.rule: Host(`your-domain.net`)
```

I noticed traefik redirect the request (http 304). If what you want is some kind of url rewriting, I don't think traefik can handle it - this should be your backend's job, users-api in your case.

IMO understanding traefik middleware behaviours is not easy. I tried to reproduce your setup with a simple nginx backend. Have a try at it:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command:
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --log.level=DEBUG
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.16.1
    labels:
      traefik.enable: 'true'
      # /users/swagger -> /swagger
      traefik.http.middlewares.replacepath-middleware.replacepath.path: /swagger
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.rule: Host(`127.0.0.1`) && PathPrefix(`/users/swagger`)
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.swagger-router.middlewares: replacepath-middleware
      # everything else (/users -> /users)
      traefik.http.routers.base-router.entrypoints: http
      traefik.http.routers.base-router.rule: Host(`127.0.0.1`)
```

Run the following commands first to create the folder and dummy pages:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec nginx mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/swagger
docker-compose exec nginx mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/users
docker-compose exec nginx sh -c "echo 'users page here' > /usr/share/nginx/html/users/index.html"                                                                   bbouchereau@bbouchereau
docker-compose exec nginx sh -c "echo 'swagger page here' > /usr/share/nginx/html/swagger/index.html"
```

The results:

- http://127.0.0.1/users/ -> users page here
- http://127.0.0.1/users/swagger/ -> redirect to http://127.0.0.1/swagger/ -> swagger page here